# Embed a sharepoint online page inside our sharepoint on-premsies is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-on-prem, iframe

we have 2 sharepoint farms which are based on the same Active Directory. one is on-premises 2013 while the other is sharepoint online. now i am trying to embed a sharepoint online classic page inside an on-premises page, so i did these steps:-

1- inside our on-premises page i added an embed web part , then i added this iframe to reference our sharepoint online page:-

```
<iframe width="100%" height="280" src="https://***.sharepoint.com/Pages/images4.aspx?IsDlg=1"></iframe>
```

2- but users will be getting these errors, on IE11, users will get this error as follow:-

> To help protect the security of information you enter into this
>   website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be
>   displayed in a frame.    What you can try   Open this content in a new
>   window

[image]

while on FireFox nothing will be shown inside the page, but when i open the browser console i found this error:-

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://***.sharepoint.com/Pages/images4.aspx?IsDlg=1 does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

so is there anything i can do regarding this?

Comment: Rather than trying to embed in your own iFrame, maybe try using the Page Viewer web part under ["Media and Content"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wksxK.png). See if that works.

Comment: @KGlasier this did not work either, and i got the exact same error as when i use iframe directly. I think the problem is with sharepoint online that it does not allow embedding its pages inside external sites.. and not a problem inside the on-premises..

Comment: The online tenant is a trusted site, right?

Comment: @KasperBoLarsen do you mean trusted site inside the IE browser?

Comment: @KasperBoLarsen i added the sharepoint online site as a trusted site on IE & Firefox but still i am getting the same error...

Comment: It seems like SharePoint online returns  same origin in the header so it will not work